# MySQL "INSERT INTO position" fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data in a table but getting error 1064:

```
INSERT INTO position(positioncode,description)
VALUES ('5000', 'President');
```

The error message says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'position(positioncode,description) VALUES ('5000',
>   'President')' at line 1

I have also insert data in other tables on the same way. Can someone help?

Comment: @Salman A not to me as far as I can tell position is not a reserved word - tho the error does go away if enclosed in backticks

Comment: @SalmanA You should repost your answer. Just write, that you don't know why :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there something wrong with mysql syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446405/is-there-something-wrong-with-mysql-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

[`position`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position) is the name of a function. Quote it by enclosing it inside backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `position` (positioncode, description) VALUES ('5000', 'President');
```

---

The exact behavior of function name parsing is described here:
[**Function Name Parsing and Resolution**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/function-resolution.html).

The description seems to suggest that:

- `CREATE TABLE count (i INT)` could be an error or not depending on [`IGNORE SPACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) setting
- `CREATE TABLE count(i INT)` is always an error

So instead of guessing, always quote built-in function names.

Comment: Strange thing - It's not listed in [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Documentation bug?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: `DATE` is also a function but `INSERT INTO date` [works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRiKkcAwtZjWwG6BwSuFFE/0)

Comment: I've upvoted, because it solves the problem (for me). But I still believe - It's an undocumented (reserved) keyword.

Comment: I needed to put space after position (name of the table), and then it worked.

Comment: @saeed no, no, no. It may or may not work depending on server settings. Use backticks so that your query is guaranteed to work, always.

Comment: I give up.. I don't understand. Adding a space doesn't fix it on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mN6vsiCMdPjbXYoTLUxgWa/0). But it works with other function names like [date](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itPfRDDFFaUkHRquVBiiZG/0) or [fields](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rceSMeaBCjxgQ3CaPdwTFd/0) even without a space.

Comment: @paul www.db-fiddle.com has `IGNORE_SPACE` enabled so both `INSERT INTO position (x) VALUES (1)` and `INSERT INTO position(x) VALUES (1)` will throw syntax error. You disable it and `position (x)` will work; `position(x)` will never work in any case. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mN6vsiCMdPjbXYoTLUxgWa/0

Comment: Found a list of those "special functions" under [Function Name Parsing and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/function-resolution.html). `POSITION` is listed there, but `DATE` and `FIELDS` are not. That expains the difference. ... Just realized - you've already posted that link in bold. My brain must have ignored anything in bold :-)